# Using ngModel on input within a directive, maintaining ng-* compatibility

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to buld a custom directive that is actually a wrapper around  input field (to simplify formatting, encapsulate animations, etc.).

One goal is to use ngModel so my directive would also be compatible with ng-maxlength, ng-required and similar directives depending on ng-Model.

I've created this plunkr with my current state:
http://embed.plnkr.co/xV8IRqTmQmKEBhRhCfBQ/

My problem is that ng-required seems to be working, but invalidates only the complete form (so that `form.$invalid` becomes `true`), but not the element itself `form.element.$invalid` remains `false`.

Also, ng-maxlength / ng-minlength does not seem to have any effect at all.

What am I missing here? Any hints welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Hi everyone and thanks a lot for your answers!

I finally figured out what the missing piece for me was: **the name attribute** which is **used by the form to reference the element MUST NOT be on the inner input field.**

It has to reside on the outer element that carries the mg-model that also gets the other directives (that interact with the ng-model).

So, to illustrate this in more detail, before my template looked like:

```
<span class="custom-input-element">
<label for="{{elementId}}-input">{{elementLabel}}<span class="required-marker" ng-if="elementRequired">*</span></label>

 <input id="{{elementId}}-input" type="text" name="{{elementName}}" ng-trim ng-model="value" ng-init="focused = false" ng-focus="focused = true" ng-blur="focused = false"/>
</span>
```

Which was used like

```
 <custom-input id="foldername" name="foldername" label="Folder Name:" 
   ng-model="folder.name" ng-maxlength="15" ng-required="true">   </custom-input>
```

Notice the `name={{elementName}}` that basically overlayed the `name="foldername"` on my directive's tag.

**After removing it from the directives template**, the form references my directive and the ngModel on my directive for validation - the input and the inner ng-model keeps hidden. Thus, the interaction with other directives like ng-maxlength and mg-minlength and also custom directives/validators works as expected.

So now, not only the form gets invalidated but also each element is validated in the expected way.

I updated my plunker where everything is working as desired now: http://embed.plnkr.co/i3SzV8H7tnkUk2K9Pq6m/

Thanks for your time and your very valuable input!

Answer (score 0):

I have created one that works, i'll try to show you the relevant part of the code.

The one really annoying point was to reattach the input and the validation to the form of the parent controller.

For this i had to cc a bunch of  private code from angular :

```
 /**
   * start cc from angular.js to modify $setValidity of ngModel to retrieve the parent form...
   */
  var VALID_CLASS = 'data-ng-valid',
    INVALID_CLASS = 'data-ng-invalid',
    PRISTINE_CLASS = 'data-ng-pristine',
    DIRTY_CLASS = 'data-ng-dirty',
    UNTOUCHED_CLASS = 'data-ng-untouched',
    TOUCHED_CLASS = 'data-ng-touched',
    PENDING_CLASS = 'data-ng-pending';
  function addSetValidityMethod(context) {
      var ctrl = context.ctrl,
          $element = context.$element,
          classCache = {},
          set = context.set,
          unset = context.unset,
          parentForm = context.parentForm,
          $animate = context.$animate;
      classCache[INVALID_CLASS] = !(classCache[VALID_CLASS] = $element.hasClass(VALID_CLASS));
      ctrl.$setValidity = setValidity;
      function setValidity(validationErrorKey, state, controller) {
        if (state === undefined) {
          createAndSet('$pending', validationErrorKey, controller);
        } else {
          unsetAndCleanup('$pending', validationErrorKey, controller);
        }
        if (!isBoolean(state)) {
          unset(ctrl.$error, validationErrorKey, controller);
          unset(ctrl.$$success, validationErrorKey, controller);
        } else {
          if (state) {
            unset(ctrl.$error, validationErrorKey, controller);
            set(ctrl.$$success, validationErrorKey, controller);
          } else {
            set(ctrl.$error, validationErrorKey, controller);
            unset(ctrl.$$success, validationErrorKey, controller);
          }
        }
        if (ctrl.$pending) {
          cachedToggleClass(PENDING_CLASS, true);
          ctrl.$valid = ctrl.$invalid = undefined;
          toggleValidationCss('', null);
        } else {
          cachedToggleClass(PENDING_CLASS, false);
          ctrl.$valid = isObjectEmpty(ctrl.$error);
          ctrl.$invalid = !ctrl.$valid;
          toggleValidationCss('', ctrl.$valid);
        }
        // re-read the state as the set/unset methods could have
        // combined state in ctrl.$error[validationError] (used for forms),
        // where setting/unsetting only increments/decrements the value,
        // and does not replace it.
        var combinedState;
        if (ctrl.$pending && ctrl.$pending[validationErrorKey]) {
          combinedState = undefined;
        } else if (ctrl.$error[validationErrorKey]) {
          combinedState = false;
        } else if (ctrl.$$success[validationErrorKey]) {
          combinedState = true;
        } else {
          combinedState = null;
        }
        toggleValidationCss(validationErrorKey, combinedState);
        parentForm.$setValidity(validationErrorKey, combinedState, ctrl);
      }
      function createAndSet(name, value, controller) {
        if (!ctrl[name]) {
          ctrl[name] = {};
        }
        set(ctrl[name], value, controller);
      }
      function unsetAndCleanup(name, value, controller) {
        if (ctrl[name]) {
          unset(ctrl[name], value, controller);
        }
        if (isObjectEmpty(ctrl[name])) {
          ctrl[name] = undefined;
        }
      }
      function cachedToggleClass(className, switchValue) {
        if (switchValue && !classCache[className]) {
          $animate.addClass($element, className);
          classCache[className] = true;
        } else if (!switchValue && classCache[className]) {
          $animate.removeClass($element, className);
          classCache[className] = false;
        }
      }
      function toggleValidationCss(validationErrorKey, isValid) {
        validationErrorKey = validationErrorKey ? '-' + snake_case(validationErrorKey, '-') : '';
        cachedToggleClass(VALID_CLASS + validationErrorKey, isValid === true);
        cachedToggleClass(INVALID_CLASS + validationErrorKey, isValid === false);
      }
    }
  function arrayRemove(array, value) {
      var index = array.indexOf(value);
      if (index >= 0) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
      }
      return index;
    }
  function isBoolean(value) {
      return typeof value === 'boolean';
    };
    var SNAKE_CASE_REGEXP = /[A-Z]/g;
    function snake_case(name, separator) {
      separator = separator || '_';
      return name.replace(SNAKE_CASE_REGEXP, function(letter, pos) {
        return (pos ? separator : '') + letter.toLowerCase();
      });
    }
  function isObjectEmpty(obj) {
    if (obj) {
      for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  };
  /**
   * end of cc
   */
```

Then in the link function :

```
function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
[...]
scope.form =  element.parent().controller('form');

var transcludedContent = transclude(scope.$parent);
// find the input
var fieldContent = findFormField(transcludedContent);

      var ngModelCtrl = angular.element(fieldContent).controller('ngModel');
      if(!ngModelCtrl){
          throw 'transcluded form field must have a ng-model';
      }

      addSetValidityMethod({
            ctrl: ngModelCtrl,
            $element: angular.element(fieldContent),
            set: function(object, property, controller) {
              var list = object[property];
              if (!list) {
                object[property] = [controller];
              } else {
                var index = list.indexOf(controller);
                if (index === -1) {
                  list.push(controller);
                }
              }
            },
            unset: function(object, property, controller) {
              var list = object[property];
              if (!list) {
                return;
              }
              arrayRemove(list, controller);
              if (list.length === 0) {
                delete object[property];
              }
            },
            parentForm: scope.form,
            $animate: $animate
          });

      scope.form.$addControl(ngModelCtrl);
      element.html(template);
       $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      element.find('.ng-form-field-content').append(transcludedContent);
      // remove the control from the form, otherwise an ng-if that hide an invalid input will block your form
      scope.$on(
              "$destroy",
              function handleDestroyEvent() {
                  scope.form.$removeControl(ngModelCtrl);
              });
```

The template is a variable containing the html of my wrapping around the input. (it generates the label, put a start if required, show a check or cross sign if field valid/invalid,...).

EDIT : 
With my directive i can do :

```
<div my-directive>
    <input/textarea/select ng-model="", required/ng-required, ng-pattern, <custom directive validation>...
</div>

And it will give something like

<div my-directive>
   <label for=<input'sname>>Texte</label>
   <input [the input will all his attrs]/>
   [some extra content]
</div>
```

I can even put some intermediary nodes or have multiple input that point to the same ng-model (like with checkbox/Radio buttons), however it won't works with different ng-models. I didn't push it that far.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Is your directive a transcluding one, meaing that you have a input in you form that you apply your directive on an it "enrices" the dom with additional elements surrounding the input (in opposite to my approach of replacing the element with my directive's template)?

Comment: Yes it is, this is why you can see transclude in the parameters of my link function :). Howeer i don't use ng-transclude. I replace the content of my dom directive by the given input surrounded by what i want do add. I edit my post to show the kind of stuff it gives.